# How can i override css button or checkbox placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

i am new user here and i am making a GUI but i am stuck at the placement of checkbox (styling)

spacing issue:

[image: spacing issue]

when i add the toggle switch(checkbox) all my aliments for the switches gets destroyed any ideas??

```
.btn-group button {
   background-color: Transparent;
    border: ;
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 29px 23px; /* Some padding */
    cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
    width: 10%; /* Set a width if needed */
    display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
    margin: 30px 1px;
}
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id = "camera" onclick="camera()"></button>
 <input id=pumptoggle type="checkbox" class="toggle-switch">
  <button id = "fish" onclick="fish()"></button>
  <button id = "outside" onclick="outside()"></button>
<button onclick="bulb()"></button>
</div>

<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="toggle-switches.css">
    </head>
```

toggle-switches.css

```
input[type=checkbox].toggle-switch {
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 6em;
    height: 3em;
    border-radius: 3em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.09s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle-switch:checked {
    background-color: #3af;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle-switch::after {
    content: '';
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    left: 0;
    transition: left 0.09s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle-switch:checked::after {
    left: 3em;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS for the `.toggle-switch`?

Comment: I have made changes to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the `!important` attribute or define new style using `id` attribute as specificity of id is more than `class` selector.`#` is use to select dom using id in css

```
#camera{
  // styles for camera
}
```

Comment: Where do i use the !important attribute? (sorry for this i never heard of this attribute before)

Comment: you have to create a new class and add properties to them. Use `!important` against those properties.
Here is a link https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

create new CSS class and use `!important` to the property  which you want to override ,
For eg,if you want to override `left-margin` you can do it as below

```
.new-class-name{
         margin-left: 10% !important 
}
```